# No external crate clap - clap-v3 rust error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The error

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `clap`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use clap;
  |     ^^^^ no external crate `clap`
```

The code I an using

```
use clap;
use regex;
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
clap-v3 = "3.0.0-beta.1"
regex = "1.4.5"
```

I have tried using

```
extern crate clap; 

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `clap`
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate clap;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

Is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the dependencies section you are specifying `clap-v3` as a dependency which you need to use like `use clap_v3;` in your code.
Maybe you wanted to add `clap` (without `-v3`) as a dependency. It has a release with the same version number.